# how to save the state of a game scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

for example I have this game:

This game does is move a bird on keyboard or mouse

```
(define-struct estado (ANCHO ALTO vel tiempo mov punto))

(define mapa (bitmap "mapa.png"))
(define Projo (bitmap "Projo.png"))
(define mario (bitmap "mario.png"))

(define (crear-mundo estado) 
  (big-bang estado
  [to-draw pintar]
  [on-tick tiempo-nuevo]
  [on-mouse click]
  [on-key cambiar-al-nuevo-mundo-teclado]
  [stop-when fin-juego]))


(define (pintar nuevo-mundo)
  (cond
    [(colisión nuevo-mundo area)
     (place-image Projo
                  (posn-x (estado-punto nuevo-mundo))
                  (posn-y (estado-punto nuevo-mundo))
                  (place-image (text (string-append "Tiempo: " (number->string (quotient (estado-tiempo nuevo-mundo) 28))) 12 "red") 40 20 mapa)
                  )]
    [else (place-image Projo
                       (posn-x (estado-punto nuevo-mundo))
                       (posn-y (estado-punto nuevo-mundo))
                       ;(place-image mario 750 500 (empty-scene 800 600))
                       ;(place-image mario 750 500 mapa)
                       (place-image (text (string-append "Tiempo: " (number->string (quotient (estado-tiempo nuevo-mundo) 28))) 12 "green") 40 20 mapa)
                       )]
    )
  )
```

create the new state of the game where make-posn is the position of the bird

```
(crear-mundo (make-estado 800 600 10 0 0 (make-posn 100 100)))
```

How I can save the state of play with the position of the bird when the game is run and what position changes

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to just use standard write and read:

```
#!racket

(define file "file.rc")

(define (save config)
  (with-output-to-file file
      (lambda () (write config))
      #:mode 'text
      #:exists 'truncate)
  config)

(define (read) 
  (with-input-from-file file
      (lambda () (read))))
```

So imagine you have a loop somewhere where you pass the new state to the next iteration. Just wrapping it in `(save state)` will save a new file over the last. `(read)` will read that file, perhaps when you start up.

You might need to check if it exists but this is basically what you need to read/store state.